# How to make a report page direction to change to "rtl"?

Tags: java, internationalization, jasper-reports

I am creating a report with *JasperReports*, using *iReport* generated jrxml file.

My application is multilingual, (English (LTR) and Persian (RTL)). In tables generated, regarding to the direction of text I need to swap the whole page direction. Plus I use **locale** feature.

I googled a lot and finally found an attribute `JRXlsAbstractExporter.PROPERTY_SHEET_DIRECTION, "RTL"` but setting this attribute in excel generated formats don't have any impact on my report.

```
    params.put(JRXlsAbstractExporter.PROPERTY_SHEET_DIRECTION, "RTL");
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,params, 
           dataSource != null ? new JRMapArrayDataSource(dataSource) : new JREmptyDataSource());
```

another thing I tried is setting this in exporter parameters as following:

```
    JRExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsAbstractExporter.PROPERTY_SHEET_DIRECTION, "RTL");
    exporter.exportReport();
```

but  setting this parameter is not allowed and I get error.
If you have any experience for how to make a report page direction (or in other words mirror the whole report in specific locale) to change please help.

Comment: I wonder what you want to achieve... When you export to Excel what is your expectation? I'm asking, because I can't really see it. Obviously, the cells won't be flipped and counted from right to left, it does not make much sense. The charts? Axis should stay the same, I believe. Well, maybe the numbers may change, but this has nothing to do with RTL... Or am I wrong about axis? You won't be flipping other types of charts... So what is the problem exactly?

Comment: For example in LTR languages if you have a column for counting it is better to be in first coulmn in left, but in RTL languages it is better to be in rightmost column. I want something like excel's page layout->right-to-left the whole page.

Comment: I understand. The problem is, it does not work like that in Excel itself. Or am I wrong? Anyway, it seems that you would need to create (at least) two report templates (one for LTR and one for RTL) and select valid one at runtime. I can't see any way to re-order columns in Excel report. Some custom exporter maybe?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I searched there is no property, you can use below util class:

```
package foo.bar.utils.export;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPrintElement;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPrintFrame;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPrintPage;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;

/**
 * Report utilities
 * Please refer to: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/523041/right-left-arabic-reports
 * There is another solution at: http://jaspermirror.sourceforge.net/
 * which is not used here
 * @author AFattahi
 *
 */
public class ReportUtils {

    private ReportUtils(){

    }
    /**
     * mirror each page layout
     * @param print
     */
    public static void mirrorLayout(JasperPrint print) {
        int pageWidth = print.getPageWidth();
        for (Object element : print.getPages()) {
            JRPrintPage page = (JRPrintPage) element;
            mirrorLayout(page.getElements(), pageWidth);
        }
    }

    /**
     * mirror a list of elements
     * @param print
     */
    protected static void mirrorLayout(List<?> elements, int totalWidth) {
        for (Iterator<?> it = elements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            JRPrintElement element = (JRPrintElement) it.next();
            int mirrorX = totalWidth - element.getX() - element.getWidth();
            element.setX(mirrorX);

            if (element instanceof JRPrintFrame) {
                JRPrintFrame frame = (JRPrintFrame) element;
                mirrorLayout(frame.getElements(), frame.getWidth());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please consider that the `JRXlsxExporter` does not support RTL (seems to be a bug in version 6) and you must `JRXlsExporter`

```
exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(out));
SimpleXlsReportConfiguration xlsReportConfig = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
xlsReportConfig.setSheetDirection(RunDirectionEnum.RTL);
exporter.setConfiguration(xlsReportConfig);
```