# How to set layout direction in jasper for RTL reports?

Tags: jasper-reports, right-to-left

I have just downloaded jasper and I am supposed to generate reports in Arabic/Farsi.

I have surfed the net and most of questions are from the past like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553540/how-to-make-a-report-page-direction-to-change-to-rtl) saying that there is no such a thing.

Please let me know what the status is for version 5.6.0.

Comment: You should post the small sample to reproduce the problem. I build reports with RTL without any problems

Comment: Thanks Alex, how do you set the layout direction cuz I used column direction and set it to RTL but it is not working for me. I have a select query like select a, b from tab so I want to see the a column right to b. How can that be achieved please let me know. thanks a lot

Comment: It dependence on Locale.  What Locale did you pass? Are you using font extensions?

Comment: BTW, for crosstab you can set propery: `<crosstab runDirection="RTL">`